# JSON Encoding Response

Tags: php, json

I have written a php code to encode a response into JSON, but itstead of the desired JSON encoding I an getting something else..can some one tell me what went wrong with the code? Thanks in advance.

here is the PHP code set

db_config.php:-

```
<?php
define('DB_USER', "root"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); 
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); 
?>
```

MSRIT_db_connect.php:-

```
<?php
class DB_CONNECT
{
    function __construct()
{
        $this->connect();
    }
    function __destruct()
{
        $this->close();
    }
    function connect()
{        
        include 'MSRIT_db_config.php';
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());
        return $con;
    }
    function close()
{
        mysql_close();
    }
}
?>
```

MSRIT_retrieve_particular_examination_result.php:-

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'MSRIT_db_connect.php';
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
if (isset($_GET["studid"]) && isset($_GET["subid"]))
{
    $studid = $_GET['studid'];
$subid = $_GET['subid'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM examination WHERE studid = '$studid' and subid = '$subid'");
    if (!empty($result))
{
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $response["examinations"] = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
                $examination = array();
        $examination["examid"] = $row["examid"];
                $examination["subid"] = $row["subid"];
                $examination["courseid"] = $row["courseid"];
                $examination["internaltype"] = $row["internaltype"];
                $examination["maxmarks"] = $row["maxmarks"];
        $examination["scored"] = $row["scored"];
        $examination["percentage"] = $row["percentage"];
        $examination["result"] = $row["result"];
                array_push($response["examinations"], $examination);
                echo json_encode($response);
    }
            $response["success"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);            
        }
    else
    {
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No exam records found";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }
else
{
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No exam record found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else
{
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

The Resultant JSON Response:-

```
{
    "examination":[
                    {
                    "examid":"1",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"27",
                    "percentage":"90",
                    "result":"PASS-Distinction"
                }
              ]
}
{  
    "examination":[
                    {
                    "examid":"1",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"27",
                    "percentage":"90",
                    "result":"PASS-Distinction"
                },
                {
                    "examid":"2",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"21",
                    "percentage":"70",
                    "result":"PASS-First Class"
                }
              ]
}
{
    "examination":[
                    {
                    "examid":"1",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"27",
                    "percentage":"90",
                    "result":"PASS-Distinction"
                },
                {
                    "examid":"2",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"21",
                    "percentage":"70",
                    "result":"PASS-First Class"
                },
                {
                    "examid":"3",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"24",
                    "percentage":"80",
                    "result":"PASS-First Class"
                }
              ]
}
{
    "examination":[
                    {
                    "examid":"1",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"27",
                    "percentage":"90",
                    "result":"PASS-Distinction"
                },
                {
                    "examid":"2",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"21",
                    "percentage":"70",
                    "result":"PASS-First Class"
                },
                {
                    "examid":"3",
                    "subid":"1",
                    "courseid":"1",
                    "internaltype":"1",
                    "maxmarks":"30",
                    "scored":"24",
                    "percentage":"80",
                    "result":"PASS-First Class"
                }
              ],
"success":1
}
```

The Desired JSON Response:-

```
{
    "examination":[
                    {
                "examid":"1",
            "subid":"1",
            "courseid":"1",
            "internaltype":"1",
            "maxmarks":"30",
            "scored":"27",
            "percentage":"90",
            "result":"PASS-Distinction"
             },
             {
                "examid":"2",
            "subid":"1",
            "courseid":"1",
            "internaltype":"1",
            "maxmarks":"30",
            "scored":"21",
            "percentage":"70",
            "result":"PASS-First Class"
             },
             {
                "examid":"3",
            "subid":"1",
            "courseid":"1",
            "internaltype":"1",
            "maxmarks":"30",
            "scored":"24",
            "percentage":"80",
            "result":"PASS-First Class"
             }
                  ],
    "success":1
}
```

Comment: Remove this `echo json_encode($response);` from inside the `while` loop.

Comment: oh damn...I did not see that one!! Thanks a lot for pointing that one out man I Can Has Cheezburger

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$response["examinations"] = array();
$examination = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $examination["examid"] = $row["examid"];
        $examination["subid"] = $row["subid"];
        $examination["courseid"] = $row["courseid"];
        $examination["internaltype"] = $row["internaltype"];
        $examination["maxmarks"] = $row["maxmarks"];
        $examination["scored"] = $row["scored"];
        $examination["percentage"] = $row["percentage"];
        $examination["result"] = $row["result"];
        array_push($response["examinations"], $examination);
    }
 echo json_encode($response);
```